# Populate one dropdown from another using php and ajax

Tags: html, ajax, drop-down-menu

so I've been working on this watching tutorials and such, but ran into a problem and need help.  So i have a dropdown list that populates another dropdown list successfully.  The problem is that I am creating the 2nd dropdown list to be populated, but want to populate an existing dropdownlist.  Could anybody give me any advice on how to do this if I did not create the 2nd dropdown list and already had one(so it would populate the 2nd dropdown list which would already exist)?

Here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form1" action="submit.php" method='POST'>


<select name="country" onchange="window.getStates()">
        <option value="">Select State</option>
        <option value="louisiana">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="texas">Texas</option>
        <option value="alabama">Alabama</option>
        <option value="mississippi">Mississippi</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getStates()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        try{
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
           }catch(e)
           {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
               }

        if(xmlhttp)
            {
                var form = document['form1'];
                var country = form['country'].value;

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "getScools.php?country="+country, true);

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
                {
                    if(this.readyState == 4)
                    {
                        var s = document.createElement("select");
                        s.name= "state";
                        s.innerHTML = this.responseText;

                        if(form['state'])
                        {
                            form.replaceChild(s, form['state']);
                        }else
                            form.insertBefore(s, form['submit']);
                    }
                }                   

                xmlhttp.send(null)
            }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Your code would replace an existing select with name "state" so can't you just set that attribute to the select you want to populate?

Comment: tried it in many different ways just not getting any action from it.  Tried to replace s with document.getElementsByName('school') and replacing 'school'.  With school being the other select in form1 that I am trying to replace instead of creating a new select.

Comment: Will you still need the 'state' select? If not, use the same code you posted but change 'state' to 'school' and it should replace that empty select with one populated

Comment: @koala_dev Thank you very much it worked perfect, must have been staring at this stuff too long lol.  Much appreciated.